# Formatting dynamically formed HTML elements created after Script is run

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic-html

So this is actually a very tricky concept to portray so here is my attempt.

I am utilizing an HTML form template in LANDesk Service Desk - tool is irrelevant but important to note that there is back-end code that I cannot touch that is generating HTML.

So basically, the tool is pulling data from a back-end database containing a list of objects. It then inputs this data into an HTML form template that I have created using variables as placeholders for the objects. The HTML is then built on the fly with however many objects are in the database. Thus, I have no way of accessing the `head` - (which means native JS, and inline CSS).

My template looks like this...

```html
<div class="my-template">
  <a class="my-template my-link">My Link</a>
</div>

<script>
  var myLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('my-link');

  for (var i = 0 ; i < myLinks.length ; i++) {
    myLinks[i].style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

When I view the source on the loaded page it looks something like this...

```html
<body>

  <!--misc. page stuff-->

  <!--First Item-->
  <div class="auto-create">
    <div class="my-template">
      <a class="my-template my-link">My-Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--Second Item-->
  <div class="auto-create">
    <div class="my-template">
      <a class="my-template my-link">My-Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

All of the elements are formatted the way I want them to be...besides the last element on each page. I have determined that this is because each time the tool is running the object through the template, it is running the script. The issue is, there is a stupid default button that they place at the bottom of each object that is broken. (This is why I have the script changing the style to display: none..should have mentioned this earlier). Basically I want to delay the execution of the script until not only the object has been run through the template...but the entire page has loaded...but I can't seem to get the last button to go away.

I know that this is a lot of poorly written words trying to form an explanation, but I really think this is impossible...but I am convinced there has to be a way. (Also, the company isn't providing us with any help in finding a workaround, so I had to basically MacGyver this one

Comment: "should have mentioned this earlier"... There is an edit link at the bottom of the question you can use to change the text so that you do mention that earlier :)

Comment: can you post a snippet of the final rendered html that shows this broken object button you wish to hide?

Comment: To execute script after the page loads typically you specify a function in the onload event of the body tag ( `<body onload='your_func'>` or via js using `document.onload` or `window.onload`.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you need to somehow affect CSS style of the last DIV block? And you can enter some HTML into the body of your template?